# Code to generate excel sheet hanging when run (using PHPEXCEL)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, phpexcel

I have the following code that is supposed to generate an excel sheet for me using PHPExcel but the problem is that it takes forever to run. I also have some Doctrine PHP code. The Doctrine code connects to the db and picks the data that I want to use to populate the Excel File. Below is the code. Please could someone tell me what is wrong

```
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
 // session_name("mediapp123456");
  session_start();
}

require_once ('bootstrap.php');
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection ( DSN );

$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('u.*')
    ->from('UserQuestionnaire u')
    ->orderBy('u.id DESC');
$row = $q->execute();

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

/** PHPExcel */
require_once 'excelreports/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
echo date('H:i:s') . " Create new PHPExcel object\n";
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set properties
echo date('H:i:s') . " Set properties\n";
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Ifeanyi Agu")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Ifeanyi Agu")
                             ->setTitle("QUSER")
                             ->setSubject("QUSER")
                             ->setDescription("QUser Generated Document")
                             ->setKeywords("xml")
                             ->setCategory("Test result file");

// Add some data
echo date('H:i:s') . " Add some data\n";

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B2:F2')
                                ->mergeCells('G2:K2')
                            ->setCellValue('I2', 'FEATURES')
                                ->mergeCells('L2:AI2')
                                ->setCellValue('W2', 'EXPECTATION')
                                ->mergeCells('AJ2:BG2')
                                ->setCellValue('AU2', 'PERCEPTION')
                                ->mergeCells('L3:03')
                                ->setCellValue('M', 'Tangible'); 

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A4', 'No')
->setCellValue('B4', 'School')
->setCellValue('C4', 'Dept')
->setCellValue('D4', 'Status')
->setCellValue('E4', 'Browse')
->setCellValue('F4', 'How Long')
->setCellValue('G4', 'Tangibility')
->setCellValue('H4', 'Reliability')
->setCellValue('I4', 'Assurance')
->setCellValue('J4', 'Responsive')
->setCellValue('K4', 'Empathy')
->setCellValue('L4', 'E1')
->setCellValue('M4', 'E2')
->setCellValue('N4', 'E3')
->setCellValue('O4', 'E4')
->setCellValue('P4', 'E5')
->setCellValue('Q4', 'E6')
->setCellValue('R4', 'E7')
->setCellValue('S4', 'E8');

$i=4;
foreach($row as $rows)
{
$i++;

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$i, ($i-4))
                                ->setCellValue('B'.$i, $rows->schoolname)
                                ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $rows->department)
                                ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $rows->status)
                                ->setCellValue('E'.$i, $rows->doyoubrowse)
                                ->setCellValue('F'.$i, $rows->browselength);

}

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// Save Excel 2007 file
echo date('H:i:s') . " Write to Excel2007 format\n";
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', FILE));

// Echo memory peak usage
echo date('H:i:s') . " Peak memory usage: " . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . " MB\r\n";

// Echo done
echo date('H:i:s') . " Done writing file.\r\n";

?>
```

Comment: Some more details could help... have you tried to profile your db query ? How much time does it take to execute ? How much rows are you supposed to print ? What do you mean by "forever" ? 20 seconds or 5 minutes ?

Comment: By forever I mean that it continues running until execution time is over. I had to increase the max execution time to 6000s but it still does not solve my problem. The problem is not from the db query. I noticed that when I comment the lines that have mergecells, thinks are better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obvious possibilities:

```
->mergeCells('L3:03')
```

suspect this should be O3 (column letter O, row three) rather than 03 (numeric zero three)

```
->setCellValue('M', 'Tangible');
```

may be the cause of some problems 'M' is a column reference rather than a cell reference

When merging and then setting a value for the merged cells, it's better to set the top-left cell of the merge range rather than a cell for the middle of the range. e.g.

```
->mergeCells('G2:K2')
->setCellValue('G2', 'FEATURES')
```

rather than

```
->mergeCells('G2:K2')
->setCellValue('I2', 'FEATURES')
```